# Is it RESTful to create complex objects in a single POST?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I have a form where users create Person records. Each Person can have several attributes -- height, weight, etc. But they can also have lists of associated data such as interests, favorite movies, etc.

I have a single form where all this data is collected. To me it seems like I should POST all of this data in a single request. But is that RESTful? My reading suggests that the  interests, favorite movies and other lists should be added in separate POST requests. But I don't think that makes sense because one of those could fail and then there would be a partial insert of the Person and it may be missing their interests or favorite movies.

Comment: If the information belongs in a single form from the user's perspective, _surely_ you should be taking it as one POST? You can do smart stuff behind the scenes if you want, but don't make client interactions more complex than they have to be.

Comment: @Donal: I strongly disagree; one of the important points of RESTful design is that the client should manage application state.  For any non-trivial problems, that involves the client keeping track of more than one state.  For the "single-form / single-POST" paradigm, you're crippling the client's ability to manage state by restricting the granularity of state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem with adding all data in one request as long as its inherently associated with the main resource (i.e. the person in your case). If interest, fav. movies etc are resources of their own, they should also be handled as such.

Comment: How does one determine if something is its own resource or not? I mean technically an individual's interests are things, but they are dependent on the existence of a Person.

Comment: In that case, I would treat Person as the resource. If a movie was something that you would want to adress seperately (e.g. by some ID) and just reference it from a person (e.g. choosing from a list), I think movie should have its own means of creation, deletion etc. and thus be treated as seperate resource. Since it can only exist in the context of a Person, I think it can be handled in one request as well.

Comment: "How does one determine if something is its own resource or not?" -> it has it's own URI.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that it depends entirely upon the addressability and uniqueness of the dependent data.

If your user-associated data is dependent upon the user (i.e., a "distinct" string, e.g. an attribute such as a string representing an (unvalidated) name of a movie), then it should be included in the POST creation of the user representation; however, if the data is independent of the user (where the data can be addressed independently of the user, e.g. a reference, such as a movie from a set of movies) then it should be added independently.

The reasoning behind this is that reference addition when bundled with the original POST implies transactionality; that is, if another user deletes the movie reference for the "favorite" movie between when it is chosen on the client and when the POST goes through, the user add will (should by that design) fail, whereas if the "favorite" movie is not associative but is just an attribute, there's nothing to fail on (attributes (presumably) cannot be invalidated by a third party).

And again, this goes very much to your specific needs, but I fall on the side of allowing the partial inserts and indicating the failures.  The proper way to handle this sort of thing if you really want to not allow partial inserts is to just implement transactions on the back end; they're the only way to truly handle a situation where a critical associated resource is removed mid-process.

Answer (score 3):

The real restriction in REST is that for a modifiable resource that you GET, you can also turn around and PUT the same representation back to change its state. Or POST. Since it's reasonable (and very common) to GET resources that are big bundles of other things, it's perfectly reasonable to PUT big bundles of things, too.

Think of resources in REST very broadly. They can map one-to-one with database rows, but they don't have to. An addressable resource can embed other addressable resources, or include links to them. As long as you're honoring your representation and the semantics of the underlying protocol's operations (i.e. HTTP GET POST PUT etc.), REST doesn't have anything to say about other design considerations that might make your life easier or harder.